# Enable registry editing (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

When logged on as a User and trying to edit the registry settings (executing a .reg file) i get the message "Registry editing disabled by your administrator".

I know that this could be changed from the policy editor. But I'd have to be logged on as User. User has no rights at all.

However I have access to administrator account. Is there any way to enable temporarily the editing of registry settings for ALL users via administrator account?

(The desired result is to change the regional settings of an existing account (or for all accounts))

Comment: Why just negative vote? If you cannot understand something or you think the question is unclear, feel free to downvote but please make a comment so that i can rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following steps

1. Search for regedit
2. Right click on that with shift key
3. You can see that there is option for run as different user.
4. Provide admin account username and password.

Comment: I can't do anything when logged on as User. The ONLY thing I can do is to have some things (like the .reg file) running on startup. I need to change the permissions from within the administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest you use `Group Policy` to make registry changes like these, saves you a truckload of complexity and central management of any changes.  There could be all sorts of problems making registry changes at logon time.  Here are the steps for Regional Settings:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer.aspx

Comment: I've seen this link but I can't get to this menu in Windows 7

Comment: Sorry I made an assumption that sounds like it may be false, do you have a server that functions as a Domain Controller where user accounts are centrally managed, or are you creating local users on this machine for different people to use?

Comment: I just created a local user with very limited rights and I need to change the regional settings.

Comment: OK my mistake, on a domain this is how you'd go about it